# Adding legend for World Ocean Base map in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, legend, basemap, arcgis-10.6

I am using [World Ocean Base](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=1e126e7520f9466c9ca28b8f28b5e500) as a background for a map I created in ArcGIS Desktop 10.6. I have been asked by a reviewer to include the meaning of the shading in the legend.

I know the shading on the base map relates to bathymetry, but is there a way to add this information to the legend as it does not automatically appear as with other layers?

Comment: It looks like there's only 8 colors on that map, so you could pretty easily figure out what range of depths each color represents by comparing to a bathymetry map (eg this one: https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=3e20c8ae23b44ca7b99af621fdc129de).

Comment: Or you can add the World Ocean Reference layer on top, which adds depth labels. https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?webmap=5ae9e138a17842688b0b79283a4353f6

Comment: I had once same problem but i had just 8 maps , so i solved by editing the final maps extending the legend by using photoshop (other options inkscape, coler)